# Задать/убрать сочитание клавиш CapsLock + Key

Tags: windows, клавиатура

Сын поиграл в игру. Теперь <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> включается при одновременно нажатых <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.  Та же история с клавишей <kbd>2</kbd>, символ ставится при одновременном нажатии <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. Для того, что бы поставить `@`, надо нажать <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

Как всё вернуть назад?

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересная информация. Век живи - век учись

Проверьте в реестре наличие ключа `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map`

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map"
```

Если ключ найден, то сделайте бэкап и удалите его. Перезагрузите компьютер.

```
reg export "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" "%HOME%/Keyboard Layout.Backup.reg"
reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map
```

Если хотите узнать больше, перед удалением почитайте статью и попробуйте приложения:

- [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)
- [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys)
- [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

Comment: В реестре ничего нет...

Comment: @MaximK, а Вы всё ещё с такими глюками в компьютере?! Вы - терпеливый человек! Попробуйте поставить программы из списка.  Должны помочь